# ERROR Cordova Salesforce andoidSDK app

Tags: package, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android, cordova

I successfully create application using command line.

```
forcedroid create
Enter your application type: hybrid_local
Enter your application name: myApp
Enter the target directory of your app : Provided the folder library 
Enter the package name for your app : com.test.myapp
```

The package & app crated on provided folder.

I am tried to open the folder/project though eclipse, The following package has been created.

1) Cordovalib 
2) LoginActivity*
3) Main Activity
4) SalesforceHybrid*
5) SmartStoreInspectorActivity*
6) Smart Sync*

Marked with * package showing the error. I have downloaded the android 6.0 sdk.

Please help me on the same.